# I am trying to get the state of my product consumers current state

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context

I am trying to log the current state of my product consumers component

My Consumer

```
<AwesomeButton
    className="text-capitalize m-auto"
    ripple
    size="medium"
    type="primary"
    cart
    disabled={inCart ? true : false}
    onPress={() => {
        value.addToCart(id);
        value.addChoices();
     }}
 >
```

Context

```
addChoices = () => {
    // this.setState(
    //   () => {
    //     return { choices: this.state.choice.push() }
    //   });
    console.log(this.state.choice)
  }
```

Comment: are you setting the state in `value.addToCard`?

Comment: What do you mean? i dont have a addtocard

Comment: `onPress={() => {
        value.addToCart(id);
        value.addChoices();
     }}` <-- are you setting it in the first function?

Comment: No how would I set it?

Comment: Would I add this.state.choice as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   onPress={() => {
                          value.addToCart(id);
                          value.addChoices(this.state.dropdownOpen);
                        }}
                      >

addChoices = dropdownOpen => {


    // this.setState(
    //   () => {
    //     return { choices: this.state.choice.push() }
    //   });
    console.log(dropdownOpen);
  };
```

Just add the state as a parameter and in the function call the parameters name